# How to put an object in session with Spring 3.1?

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations

I have two controllers, say controllerA and controllerB.  ControllerA has a consultation object that I need to send to a consultation jsp.  I'm using return forward: consultation.
However, after I reach the jsp, I need the consultation object both for that jsp and to use in another controller, if the user presses a confirm button.

I tried @SessionAttributes and found it's only available for the first controllerA.  Then I tried using flashAttributes, but I wasn't able to verify if the redirect worked as the form in the jsp needs to be blank the first time it loads and it threw an error: Expected session attribute 'consultation'.

```
redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("AttributeName", value);
    return "redirect:consultation";
```

I ended up with using HttpSession as a workaround.  So in this situation, is that the proper way to do this or did I just not set this up right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is the correct way to do this in my case.

I put the object in the session and when the user is on the jsp page, the controller is fired from a submit button.  Then everything I need is in the session and I retrieve it.